# React Native: Why long text is not shown under Text component?

Tags: react-native, server, textview, large-data, invisible

Need to show the long text, which is retrieved from server.

I'm using web storm and react native 0.57

```
<Text>{this.state.responseText}</Text>
```

Should be able to view long text under the text tag. Why long text is not shown under Text component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I was also facing same problem. Use WebView instead of text component.

```
<WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{html: this.state.responseText}}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `numberOfLine = {}` property of text component.

Comment: Let me try this solution. Thanks

Comment: noOfLines is used to set the number of lines for a TextInput

Comment: please check this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines

Answer (score 0):

you can edit style of your text component and make fontsize larger

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>{this.state.responseText}</Text>
```